# Magento order upload image resolution restriction

Tags: magento

I have magento order upload extension which allow to user to upload images of each order. I want to ask is there a limit of image resolution when the customer uploading photos. I have limit of 8mb image size. But when i try to upload image 2500px/2500px - nothing happened. With lower image resolution i don't have that problem. In module demo I can upload images with high resolution.  I dont think that is settings of the plugin. Is it something from magento settings or from server settings?

Comment: Just to be sure, that 2500x2500px image was less than 8MB? if the limit is file size and not image dimensions, make sure those are fine.

Comment: Its less than 8mb. It's 2.5Mb